# Fatal Exception: android.app.RecoverableSecurityException has no access to content://media/external/images/media/

Tags: android-studio

This crash only occurred on OS 10 api level 28 just. In other words I cannot delete images or videos from external storage in OS 10. I read many things they all said this is drawback of OS 10. Maybe some issue with permissions. Also crashed on videos too here is video file crash

Fatal Exception: android.app.RecoverableSecurityException
has no access to content://media/external/video/media/83463

here is code to delete images

```
 ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            for (Uri uri : ListUri)
                resolver.delete(uri, null, null);
```

I read many things they all said this is drawback of OS 10.